# Inequality of Positive-definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In this question matrix $A$ is positive-definite if and only if $\forall x\ne0 :x^TAx>0$. ($A$ is not necessarily symmetric)

Let $D$ be a positive-definite matrix such that it has block form:

$$D=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & C  \\
C^T & B  \end{array} \right)$$

How can we prove that $\det D\leq\det A\det B$?

EDIT1: From the perspective of the first answer I want to sum up something.

- It's true that

$$D=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & C  \\
C^T & B  \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
I & 0  \\
C^TA^{-1} & I  \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & C  \\
0 & B-C^TA^{-1}C  \end{array} \right)$$

so $\det D=\det A\det (B-C^TA^{-1}C)$.

It's also true that $\det A>0$ because every real eigenvalues of $A$ is greater than $0$ and all complex eigenvalues exist in pairs.

Now we need to prove that $$\det B>\det(B-C^TA^{-1}C)$$

- The usual way when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric haven't worked yet because: (1) we don't know for sure if $(B-C^TA^{-1}C)$ is definite positive and (2) we don't know for sure if $\det(M+N)>\det(N)$ if $M$ and $N$ are definite positive.

I also want to point out that definite positive matrices (in this question) can have complex eigenvalues.

It would be great if you answer with details, not with references since almost every references consider positive-definite matrices to be symmetric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to prove is not necessarily true. Here is a random counterexample:

$$
D=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A&C\\ \hline C^T&B\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
2&-3&1&0\\
2&2&0&-1\\
\hline
1&0&2&1\\
0&-1&-2&2
\end{array}\right].
$$
According to your definition, a matrix is "positive definite" if and only if its symmetric part is positive definite in the conventional sense. Now, WolframAlpha [reckons](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues%20%7B%7B4%2C-1%2C2%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C4%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B2%2C0%2C4%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-2%2C-1%2C4%7D%7D) that the eigenvalues of
$$
D+D^T=\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
4&-1&2&0\\
-1&4&0&-2\\
\hline
2&0&4&-1\\
0&-2&-1&4
\end{array}\right]
$$
are $4-\sqrt{5}$ and $4+\sqrt{5}$ (each of multiplicity 2). Hence $D$ is "positive definite". WolframAlpha also reckons that [$\det(D)=61$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20%7B%7B2%2C-3%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%2C0%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C-2%2C2%7D%7D) However,
$$\det(A)\det(B)=10\times6=60<\det(D).$$

Comment: congrat +500 such a releasing answer... ugmm I have been trying to disprove this so long

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks. Apparently, the chance of getting a counterexample is small. I've just run a casual numerical experiment. If $C=I$ and the entries of $A$ and $B$ are taken from the range $[-10,10]$, then only 11% of those "positive definite" $D$s would violate the inequality in question. If the range is limited to $[-2,2]$, the proportion is even smaller -- 5.7%. So, if one tries only a few random examples without controlling the sizes of the entries of $A$ and $B$ carefully, one may not see any counterexample at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need two facts to prove the result. One is about the [determinant of the block matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).
$$\det D = \det A \det (B-C^\top A^{-1}C)$$
The other one is called Schur's complement.
See page 66  [here](http://w3.ele.tue.nl/fileadmin/ele/MBS/CS/Files/Courses/DISClmi/lmis1.pdf).
$$D > 0 \leftrightarrow A > 0, B - C^\top A^{-1}C >0 $$

Note that $C^\top A^{-1}C \geq 0$ due to $A > 0$. This gives $B > 0$. From this you get 
$$\det (B-C^\top A^{-1}C) \leq \det B$$
Hence, $$\det D \leq \det A \det B$$

Edit: The determinant inequality follows from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65424/determinant-of-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices)

Edit #2 (Proof of $D > 0 \rightarrow A > 0 $): We assume $A$ to be square, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Note that when $A$ is square, it follows from the structure of $D$ that $B$ is square as well, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Take $x \in  \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
$$\begin{pmatrix} x^{\top} & 0 \end{pmatrix}D\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = x^{\top}Ax$$
Since $D$ is positive definite ($y^{\top}Dy >0 \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+m) \times (n+m)}$), $x^{\top}Ax > 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Hence, $A$ is positive definite.
For the implication, $D > 0 \rightarrow B - C^\top A^{-1}C >0 $ I haven't been able to come up with a proof that doesn't require symmetricity assumption.

Comment: can you explain a litter more explicitly? This is exactly the way I prove in the case all is symmetric.

Comment: also in the mathoverflow site they assert the inequality for nonnegative HERMITIAN matrices only

Comment: @Mr.T The Hermitian condition is for the Minkowski determinant theorem. There is another proof of the determinant inequality that doesn't make use of this assumption. It is in the comments section of the same answer there.

Comment: @Mr.T None of the results here are limited to symmetric matrices. Both Schur's complement and the determinant identity hold under the assumptions you had in your question.

Comment: That's exactly why I ask this question. can you explain by using only the assumptions in the question? Many thankss!

Comment: @Mr.T $A$ being square and $D > 0$ imply $A > 0$. From this you have the invertibility of $A$, which is the only thing you need for the determinant identity. For the proof of the determinant inequality the proof given by Suvrit for the question I gave a link to does not make use of symmetricity assumption.

Comment: And once again the definition of definite-positive in this question is different from many materials.
What about the Schur complement condition?

Comment: why A being square?

Comment: @Mr.T Schur's complement does not require symmetricity as far as I know. So your definition is covered there as well.

Comment: Can you prove that explicitly?

Comment: @Mr.T If $A$ is square, you can take the vector $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ where $x$ agrees with the dimension of $A$ and pre-/post-multiply $D$ by its tranpose/it. From that you can conclude $A > 0$.

Comment: I don't want to extend more and more... Can you just edit the question so that i can approach it :) really sorry

Comment: @Mr.T Prove what explicitly? Schur's complement? I am sure you can find it on the internet somewhere. It must have a standard proof.

Comment: How to prove $D > 0 \leftrightarrow A > 0, B - C^\top A^{-1}C >0 $?

Comment: I don't understand the last argument

Comment: @Mr.T it is a typo. swap the z and 0 in that vector

Comment: After calculating I think it only proves that $B$ is positive definite.

Comment: @Mr.T You are right. I jumped too quickly to that conclusion. I'll try to fix it.