# Proving $\det\bf M\le\det A\det D$ for an n.n.d. block matrix $\mathbf M=\left[\begin{matrix}\bf A & \bf B\\\bf B^\top & \bf D \\\end{matrix}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

> Let $\mathbf M=\left[\begin{matrix}\bf A & \bf B\\\bf B^\top & \bf D \\\end{matrix}\right]$ be a symmetric n.n.d. matrix where $\bf A$ is square. Show that $\det\bf M\le\det A\det D$.

I guess this result is related to the standard inequality $\det \mathbf A\le\prod_{i=1}^na_{ii}$ for an n.n.d. matrix $\mathbf A=((a_{ij}))$ of order $n$.

It can be shown that $\det\mathbf M=\det\mathbf A\det(\mathbf D-\mathbf{B^\top A^{-1}B})$ when $\bf A$ is nonsingular.

Moreover, $\bf M$ will be n.n.d. iff $\bf A$ and $\mathbf D-\mathbf{B^\top A^{-1}B}$ are n.n.d., as is seen from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280671/definiteness-of-a-general-partitioned-matrix-mathbf-m-left-beginmatrix-bf) post.

Now, $\det(\mathbf D-\mathbf{B^\top A^{-1}B})=\det(\mathbf D -\mathbf C)$, say

$=\det \mathbf D\det(\mathbf I-\mathbf{D^{-1}C})$

$=(\det\mathbf D)\prod_i(1-d_{i})$ where $d_{i}$'s are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{D^{-1}C}$.

If I could somehow conclude that the $d_i$'s are nonnegative (or possibly the matrix $\mathbf{D^{-1}C}$ is n.n.d.), then the product $\prod_i(1-d_{i})$ becomes bounded above by $1$ and my required inequality follows. Is this somewhat apparent? Also, it is seen that equality should hold in the required inequality iff $\mathbf B=\mathbf O$, which means that with my argument the $d_i$'s must be zero. Is this the correct way to proceed?

Comment: If $D$ is symmetric and $C$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, then the eigenvalues of $D -C$ are less than the eigenvalues of $D$. This follows from a special case of the Weyls inequalities. Or think about it like this: first reduce to the case where everything is positive definite by adding a large multiple of $I$. Then consider the ellipsoids associated with all of the matrices. The eigenvalues of one matrix are all less than another iff the ellipsoid from one matrix contains that of the other

Comment: @NickAlger Unfortunately, I am currently learning the subject at a less advanced level.

Comment: Similar post found: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915051/inequality-of-positive-definite-matrix.