# How to prove this matrix inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, transpose

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ real matrix, and let $B$ be an $n\times(n-m)$ real matrix, please prove this matrix inequality.  $A^{\prime}$ represents the transpose of the matrix.
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
A^{\prime}A&A^{\prime}B\\
B^{\prime}A&B^{\prime}B\\
\end{bmatrix}
\le \det(A^{\prime}A)\det(B^{\prime}B)
$$

This problem comes with a constraint, which is to primarily utilize basic matrix operations. My approach is to decompose the left matrix into the product of several other matrices, I've been thinking for a long time, but I have no other ideas.

Comment: first argue your matrix on the left hand side is real symmetric PSD and that if $A$ or $B$ are not injective then the determinant is $0$ on both sides of the inequality.  Then use a duplicate result on this site, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276355/if-m-left-beginmatrix-a-b-bt-c-endmatrix-right-is-a-positive .  It isn't clear what a constraint of primarily "utilizing basic matrix operations" means -- this is one of many reasons why it is expected that original posters show a serious attempt at solving their problem.